# Cannot find SublimeREPL from list of package

Tags: sublimetext2

I am trying to add the packages install in sublime text. I have tried the following below:

1. in Sublime press Ctrl+Shift+P (linux command in ST for 'goto anything')
2. Type in 'install',**
3. click on 'sublime package control: install package'.
4. Then select SublimeREPL. It will install it automatically.
5. To use it go to Tools>sublimerepl>python from the menus.

But I'm stuck at step 4. I can't find sublimeREPL from the list. There is nothing with such name.

Comment: If it's not on the list, then it's already installed. Select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open up `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages` and look for a folder named `SublimeREPL`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have SublimeREPL isntalled. To check it `"Preferences -> Browse Packages"` and see if there's a folder named `SublimeREPL`.

If it is there, you may not have it enabled. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` select `Package Control: Enable Pacakge`. In the popup, select `SublimeREPL`.